# How to obtain the string value of an Element?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

I want to do something like this:

```
getValue :: Element -> String
getValue x = do
    v <- get UI.value x
    v
```

However, an error is thrown; the expected type of `get UI.value x` is `[String]` but the actual type is `UI String`?

But if I change the type signature to `getValue :: Element -> UI String`, my last `v` gets the error of expected type `UI String` while its actual type is `String`.

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
myfunction window = do
    words <- getElementsByClassName window "word"
    let strs = map getValue words
```

Since I can't say `let strs = map (\x -> v <- get UI.value x) words`.

When I only have one element to deal with, I'm fine:

```
filename <- chooser # get UI.value
liftIO $ print filename
unless (null filename) $ do
    prevRows <- getElementsByClassName w "row"
    mapM_ delete prevRows
    elems <- liftIO $ readJSON filename
    mapM_ (element table # addRow) elems
```

Comment: Presumably you just want `getValue :: Element -> UI String; getValue = get UI.value`. Possibly not even worth making a definition. Disclaimer: I have never used threepenny or even looked at its documentation, so this is speculation based on the info in the question rather than expertise.

Comment: So threepenny uses a UI monad, kind of like IO. `get UI.value` would return a `UI String`, which I'm trying to use `<-` on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `get UI.value x` has type `UI String` as opposed to `String`, the correct definition of `getValue` needs to be in the `UI` monad as well:

```
-- Still not well-typed
getValue :: Element -> UI String
getValue x = do
    v <- get UI.value x
    v
```

However, then your next problem is that after you bind `get UI.value x` to `v`, `v` has type `String`, not `UI String`, so you need to `return` it, leading to the correct version

```
getValue :: Element -> UI String
getValue x = do
    v <- get UI.value x
    return v
```

which of course [can be simplified](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) as

```
getValue :: Element -> UI String
getValue x = get UI.value x
```

or η-reduced further to

```
getValue :: Element -> UI String
getValue = get UI.value
```

Since `UI` is a monad, you can use standard monad combinators like [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM) to turn `getValue :: Element -> UI String` into `mapM getValue :: [Element] -> UI [String]`:

```
myfunction window = do
    words <- getElementsByClassName window "word"
    strs <- mapM (get UI.value) words
    -- ... rest of `myfunction` can use `strs`
```

Note that `myfunction` of course is still in `UI`.

Comment: @allidoiswin You cannot get a `String` out of a `UI String`. But you can teach an operation that's expecting a `String` how to deal with getting a `UI String` instead; and that is what you are doing with `readFile`: teaching an operation that knows how to muck with a `FilePath` how to muck with a `UI FilePath` instead. The `do` syntax tries to hide this inversion of control -- but as you are observing, not very well, so if you have this wrong impression of what can be done, you will be confused often!

Comment: @DanielWagner could you link me to a resource for this? Very interesting.

Comment: @allidoiswin There are many, many monad tutorials out there. When I was learning, I especially enjoyed [You Could Have Invented Monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) and [All About Monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads).